# wordpress post gallery functions does not show the number of posts

Tags: wordpress, image, printing

hi i have this code i created in content-gallery.php
but when i use printf to show the number of photos within the post does not show it

it must be print
[This Post Gallery Contains 9 Photos.]
but does not work. why?
when my errors?

```
<?php

$the_images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'   => $post->ID, // Pass the ID of a post or Page to get its children. Pass 0 to get attachments without parent. Pass null to get any child regardless of parent.
    'post_mime_type'=> 'image', // A full or partial mime-type, e.g. image, video, video/mp4, which is matched against a post's post_mime_type field.
    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'numberposts'   => 999
));

if ( !empty($the_images) ) {
    $the_total_images = count($the_images);
    $the_images       = array_slice($the_images, 0, 10); // prin_r form 0 to 10 images
?>

<p><strong>
    <?php printf (_n('This Post Gallery Contains %s Photo.', 'This Post Gallery Contains %s Photos.', $the_total_images, 'the-bootstrap'), $the_total_images); ?>
</strong></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sprintf()` instead of `printf()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sprintf()` instead of `printf()`.

Also, make sure to not have any spaces when using functions. spaces are alright once your within the brackets, but have the space in `printf ()` is bad practice and most of the time errors or doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `the_images` is not empty. If it is empty then `$the_total_images` is never set.

I don't understand your usage of array_slice either. Surely it would be more efficient to only get 10 posts.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
<?php
global $post;

$the_images = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );

$the_total_images = ( $the_images ) ? count( $the_images ) : 0;
$image_count_text = sprintf( _n( 'This Post Gallery Contains %s Photo.', 'This Post Gallery Contains %s Photos.', $the_total_images, 'the-bootstrap' ), $the_total_images); ?>

<p><strong><?php echo $image_count_text; ?></strong></p>
```

`$the_total_images` is no longer dependent on the outcome of `get_posts()`. I've left it loading all image attachments but I think a better solution could be found if you're only going to use 10.